# Position relative div getting different offset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following html, I'm getting `topOffset` of each div, but child div under `position:relative` div are taking unexpected `offset`, I can't remove `position`, any help/solution would be great.

I'm trying to set some `js` behavior on some randomly generating div with `offset`.

Note: I can only use `javascript` not `jq`.

```js
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop + " " + document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop + " " + document.getElementById('div2-child').offsetTop;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#div2 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
#div2-child {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?
<div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?</div>
<div id="div2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?
  <div id="div2-child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?</div>
</div>
<p id=demo></p>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me.  What are you expecting?

Comment: `#div2-child` offset is less than `#div2`

Comment: It's a relative offset.  It's inside `#div2` so yes.  It's 71px from the top of the parent div.  If you want the overall offset then just add it to the parent offset.

Comment: Even if you can't remove `position`, can you override it?

Comment: Actually in my `project` all divs are generates randomly and their Ids too, so I'm not able to use your approach @Archer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Comment: Then you aren't explaining your actual problem properly.  I suspect ^^ that comment is correct.

Comment: `element.getBoundingClientRect()` worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) `HTMLElement.offsetTop` returns position relative to the parent element . So in your example `document.getElementById('div2-child').offsetTop` returns top position relative to `div2`

So, if you want the position relative to window(viewport) you need to add child position with it's parent position like below:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop + " " + document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop + " " + (document.getElementById('div2-child').offsetParent.offsetTop + document.getElementById('div2-child').offsetTop);
```

or you could use [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) as below:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop + " " + document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop + " " + (document.getElementById('div2-child').getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* Get the position of an element relative to the document body
*/
function absoluteOffset(el) {
  var offset = el.offsetTop
  var offsetParent = el.offsetParent
  if (offsetParent === document.body) {
    return offset
  }
  return offset + absoluteOffset(offsetParent)
}
```

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
var div2Child = document.getElementById('div2-child')
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = absoluteOffset(div1) + ' ' + absoluteOffset(div2) + ' ' + absoluteOffset(div2Child)

/**
* Get the position of an element relative to the document body
*/
function absoluteOffset(el) {
  var offset = el.offsetTop
  var offsetParent = el.offsetParent
  if (offsetParent === document.body) {
    return offset
  }
  return offset + absoluteOffset(offsetParent)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#div2 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
#div2-child {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?
<div id="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?</div>
<div id="div2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?
  <div id="div2-child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, harum, officia quam magni provident tempora debitis mollitia placeat ducimus atque nobis fugit voluptatibus nisi commodi doloremque hic perspiciatis sint odit?</div>
</div>
<p id=demo></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but `element.getBoundingClientRect()` worked.